# Codedeploy-agent error when run in amazon linux instance

Tags: shell, aws-code-deploy, amazon-linux

When I create a new deploy in AWSCodeDeploy with GitHub I receive this fail message:

```
Error CodeScriptFailed
Script Namescripts/stop_server.sh
MessageScript at specified location: scripts/stop_server.sh run as user ubuntu failed with exit code 1
Log TailLifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
Script - scripts/stop_server.sh
[stderr]su: user ubuntu does not exist
```

But, my instance is an Amazon Linux Instance and don't have a `ubuntu` user, anybody know anything about this?

The script that a try to run is:

```
# scripts/stop_server.sh
#!/bin/bash
forever stop .
```

My appspec.yml file:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
   - source: /
     destination: /home/ec2-user
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 5
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 5
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: scripts/stop_server.sh
      timeout: 5
      runas: root
```

Codedeploy-agent version `agent_version: OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1095_rpm`

Answer (score 0):

[Application stop](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html) usually refers to appspec.yml in previous successful deployment archive. Either empty  `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-archive/deployment-instructions/` or you may use `BeforeInstall` hook to execute stop script.

Comment: Hi @Ravi sorry about long time to response you.
Thanks for help.
I resolved the problem deleting the application that I have problem and create a new one. I believe that the problem is exacly what you sad, the ApplicationStop hook.

Answer (score 0):

The code deploy create temporary application inside /opt/code-deploy/.... path. If the deployment fails normally it starts from the temporary directory next time. If you want to get rid of the error pointing by deployment, you should check the particular script file in the temporary directory and edit it.